# Best way to delete bad record from csv file using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

The following script works by adding the bad records to the exception my file.

I just need the best way to delete the bad records from the source file after it's copied.

```vb
Public Sub readopentextfile()
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Dim oFS, oFSO, oFSW
Dim stext As String
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'/ Open new DailySalesOrds for reading
Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\DailySalesOrds.csv", ForReading)

'/ Open exception file for writing
Set oFSW = oFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\DailySalesOrderExcep.csv", ForAppending)

'/ Read each record and count commas if 21 or more add record to exception file
Do Until oFS.AtEndOfStream
         stext = oFS.ReadLine
    Do
    c = InStr(c + 1, stext, ",")
        If c <> 0 Then Count = Count + 1
    Loop Until c = 0

'Debug.Print Count
    If Count >= 21 Then
       oFSW.Write (vbNewLine & stext)
    End If
c = 0
Count = 0
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

- Write the good lines to a new file
- Rename the source file with the extension .bak
- Rename the new file as the original source file

Comment: I realize I'am still a novice at this.. But it